# android kotlin Error camera2 Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

My code:
Activity:

```
jpegSizes = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)?.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            for(i in 0 until jpegSizes!!.size){
                val width = jpegSizes!![i].width
                val height = jpegSizes!![i].height
                Log.i(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "jpegSizes width x height : $width x $height")
            }
        }

//width and height in log jpegSizes 
        imageReader1 = ImageReader.newInstance(1280, 720, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2)

myTextureView.surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener{
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
                open_camera()
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(
                surface: SurfaceTexture,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {

            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {

            }

        }
```

fun open_camera

```
fun open_camera(width: Int, height: Int) {
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraManager.cameraIdList[0], object :CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = camera

                capReq = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                val texture = myTextureView.surfaceTexture
                texture?.setDefaultBufferSize(1280, 720)

                var surface = Surface(texture)

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader1.surface, imageReader2.surface, imageReader3.surface, imageReader4.surface, imageReader5.surface, imageReader6.surface, imageReader7.surface, imageReader8.surface, imageReader9.surface), object :CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        cameraCaptureSession = session
                        cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(capReq.build(), null, null)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    }

                }, handler)
                capReq.addTarget(surface)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                val errorMsg = when(error) {
                    ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE -> "Fatal (device)"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED -> "Device policy"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE -> "Camera in use"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE -> "Fatal (service)"
                    ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE -> "Maximum cameras in use"
                    else -> "Unknown"
                }
                Log.e(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "Error when trying to connect camera $errorMsg")
            }

        }, handler)
    }
```

The code completely works correctly in the emulator, however, when running on any device, I get the following error:

```
17:34:48.930  I  [unnamed-415-19](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:0,p:-1,c:415) setConsumerName: unnamed-415-19
17:34:48.931  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:0,p:-1,c:415) setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-0-415-1
17:34:48.932  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:0,p:-1,c:415) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=2016
17:34:48.990  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:0,p:-1,c:415) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1280 height=720
17:34:48.990  D  suface:Surface(name=android.graphics.SurfaceTexture@476f44f)/@0x93047dc
17:34:48.990  D  imageReader1.surface:Surface(name=null)/@0xf9bd0e5
17:34:48.991  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1] attachToContext
17:34:49.039  V  onWindowFocus: androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout{e745801 VFE...... .F.....D 0,0-1080,2016 #7f09014e app:id/drawer} softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810500
17:34:49.081  D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e5e315e00,api=1)
17:34:49.083  D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x7e5e315e00,api=1)
17:34:49.410  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:4,p:393,c:415) connect(P): api=4 producer=(393:???) producerControlledByApp=true
17:34:49.410  I  [SurfaceTexture-0-415-1](this:0x7e75a6d800,id:19,api:4,p:393,c:415) setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: maxDequeuedBuffers = 8
17:34:49.411  I  [ImageReader-1280x720f100m2-415-9](this:0x7e5e381000,id:10,api:4,p:393,c:415) connect(P): api=4 producer=(393:???) producerControlledByApp=false
17:34:49.412  W  Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:344: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
17:34:49.416  E  Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
```

if i remove from `cameraDevice.createCaptureSession` all `imageReader.surface` - then the activity starts and the preview works, but of course you can’t take pictures...

Settings width/height imageReader and textureView equal

Please help me to overcome this error...